# Automation Of Multiple XML Files Validation

Tags: java, xml, plsql, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm wondering if it's possible to automate the whole xml validation process within a file server?

- reading multiple xml files from a directory,
- validating the files against a tree of xsd schema files,
- and then spitting out an output of success/failure with errors,
- and maybe inserting all of these information in a database for easier tracking of changes

The system mostly uses JAVA and PL/SQL for dealing with files.

I've done some research for this, however, I'm not too familiar with XML technologies and so I'm uncertain whether what I'm looking for can be done with either

- commercial products (ie. xml editors such as oxygenXML, stylus studio, xmlspy, altova, etc) or
- open source (CAM toolkit, Apache Xerces2 Java, SOAPUI, etc).

Any recommendations/input/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xmllint for validation and parsing. This is included in most version of linux by default and easy to use:

```
xmllint --noout --schema <xsd file> <xml file>
```

For Windows I prefer Altova xmlspy.

Answer (score 0):

I have used and recommend the oracle xml parser "xml" on the command line as part of a pipeline to validate xml files on ingress and egress.

- This caught issues with character encoding and other mistakes at various times.

And the more detailed level used the [Multi Schema Validator](https://github.com/kohsuke/msv)  initially from sun to validate to arbitrary external schema (not defined within the file).

- This caught schema errors that remote parties sent.
- Functioned as part of a secure ingress filter to validate content before ingest.

For the early phases of the project (with low tech partners) I used the [html tidy](https://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) tool to force invalid xml into a valid form to force the data into our systems even if it was created invalid.

- Found unclosed attributes.
- Invalid characters.
- Unclosed entities.

Both of these were for various parts of a big corporate B2B system.